# Error on displaying the date On March 2011

Tags: php

```
$startDay = "2011-03-31"; 

for($i=0; $i<6; $i++)
{
  $startDaysArr[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDay) - 3600*24*$i);

}

$startDaysArr = array_reverse($startDaysArr, FALSE);
```

Duo to **clocks move forward one hour** on **2011-03-27**, so the output are not correct when `$startDay = "2011-03-31 00:00:00"`after running the above code.

As seen from result below, the 2011-03-27 is missing. Is there anyone can help me? Really appreciate for your help.

**-----Output When $startDaysArr = "2011-03-31 00:00:00"----**

```
Array                           //Correct One:
(
    [25] => 2011-03-25          // 2011-03-26
    [26] => 2011-03-26          // 2011-03-27 
    [27] => 2011-03-28          // 2011-03-28 
    [28] => 2011-03-29          // 2011-03-29 
    [29] => 2011-03-30          // 2011-03-30 
    [30] => 2011-03-31          // 2011-03-31 
)
```

Comment: What's going on if you start at "2011-03-31 01:00:00" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work from noon rather than midnight:

```
$startDay = "2011-03-31";
$currDay = $startDay;
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $startDaysArr[] = $currDay;
    $currDay = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime ($currDay . " 11:59") - 3600 * 24 * $i);
}
```

That way, variations of an hour or so will have no effect whatsoever. The fact that you're only ever storing the date component, and using that combined with a time of `11:59`, means that subtraction of 24 hours should be safe (no cumulative errors).

Answer (score 1):

Almost identical to another question I've already answered today:

```
$startDaysArr = array();
$startDate = new DateTime("2011-03-31",new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));

for($i=0; $i<6; $i++)
{
   $startDaysArr[] = $startDate->format("Y-m-d");
   $startDate->modify("-1 day");
}

$startDaysArr = array_reverse($startDaysArr, FALSE);
```

Yes, it is because the clocks change, so don't rely on subtracting the number of minutes in x days, but use "DST safe" dateTime objects and move into the world of "modern" (rather thn last decade's) PHP

Answer (score 0):

When the hour offset is that much of a problem why not add a safe time to the date ?

$startDay = "2011-03-31 7:00";

The function strtotime expects to be given a string containing a US English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just the `strtotime` function? Change this line:

```
$startDaysArr[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$startDay -$i day"));
```